# Apache AH01276: Cannot serve directory Error

Tags: php, apache, server

I started getting the following error without making any changes to my site and project. I started getting this as soon as I moved it to the server. I tried many ways but failed in all of them.
Here are my server settings. I tried all the methods available on the internet but my problem still persists.

**Error Log:**

```
[Fri Sep 03 19:38:29.865532 2021] [autoindex:error] [pid 37493:tid 47162220349184] [client 88.231.168.12:61248] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/gorevyap/public_html/anasayfa/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

Apache:
**DirectoryIndex Priority index.html index.php**

.htaccess Public_html

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
RewriteRule ^index$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^anasayfa$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^login$ login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^giris-yap$ login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^register$ register.php [L]
RewriteRule ^kayit-ol$ register.php [L]
RewriteRule ^cikis-yap$ logout.php [L]
RewriteRule ^ayarlarim$ ayarlarim.php [L]
RewriteRule ^sikca-sorulan-sorular$ sss.php [L]
RewriteRule ^market$ market.php [L]
RewriteRule ^siparislerim$ siparislerim.php [L]
RewriteRule ^gorev-bitir$ gorevtamamla.php [L]
RewriteRule ^anketler$ anketler.php [L]
RewriteRule ^duyurular$ duyurular.php [L]
RewriteRule ^odeme-talebi$ odeme-talebi.php [L]
RewriteRule ^sms_onay$ sms_onay.php [L]
RewriteRule ^ref-sistemi$ ref-sistemi.php [L]
RewriteRule ^gorevlerim$ gorevlerim.php [L]
RewriteRule ^sifremi-unuttum$ forget-pass.php [L]
RewriteRule ^gorev-yayinla$ gorev-ekle-kullanici.php [L]
RewriteRule ^gunluk-bonus$ gunluk-bonus.php [L]
RewriteRule ^destek-taleplerim$ destek-taleplerim.php [L]
RewriteRule ^yeni-destek-talebi$ yeni-destek-talebi.php [L]
RewriteRule ^destek$ ticket.php [L]
RewriteRule ^bakiye-yukle$ bakiye-yukle.php [L]
RewriteRule ^btc-puan-yukle$ btc-puan-yukle.php [L]
RewriteRule ^odeme-bildir$ odeme-bildir.php [L]
RewriteRule ^odeme-bildirimlerim$ odeme-bildirimlerim.php [L]
RewriteRule ^mail_onay$ mail_onay.php [L]
RewriteRule ^rank-paketleri$ rank-paketleri.php [L]
RewriteRule ^blog$ blog.php [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/$ blog.php [L]
RewriteRule ^bekleyen-kanitlarim$ bekleyen-kanitlarim.php [L]
RewriteRule ^gk-grvlerim$ gk-grvlerim.php [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)$ blog.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/$ blog-post.php?yazipri=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^go/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)$ ads_go.php?a=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^urun/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)$ urun-detay.php?sefurl=$1 [L,QSA]

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: Have you checked that mod_rewrite is enabled on your new host?

Comment: @cOle2 Yes mod_rewrite is active on my server and I am using CENTOS 7.9

Comment: Just noticed you have a `RewriteCond` of port 80 but then you redirect to https which would be port 443 on the next request and those RewriteRules would not apply due to the preceeding RewriteCond.

Comment: @cOle2 Thank you for your valuable comment Cole, how can I understand this? So what solution should I follow?

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on my rewrite rules but I think second RewriteCond of port 443 after the redirect might do the trick.

Comment: @cOle2 Thank you very much for your help Cole. But my knowledge of these rules is 0 :/ I don't know how to solve this at all

Comment: `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443` after `RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]` is what I meant in the above comment. Maybe someone else will chime in...

Comment: Thanks for everything @cOle2 i tried but 

This page is not working ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS